# Syntax error executing query from python (postgres)

Tags: python, postgresql

I am getting syntax error in sql query statement stored in cur to store multiple list value

```
nam = ['sau','sing','loe','sta'] 
for d in nam:
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES ({})""", .format(d))
    print(len(nam))'
```

getting error for the following statement

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES ({})""", .format(d))
```

the erroe message giving is

```
 File "C:\Users\surya\Desktop\whtscric\fe.py", line 12
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES ({})""", .format(d))
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should not use string formatting like this to add parameters to your queries, as it's vulnerable to SQL injection. A better practice is to follow the [psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and pass variables as arguments to `cur.execute`.

Comment: Well, you're passing two arguments to `execute` - separated by a comma - and the second one is just `.format(d)`, which is not a valid Python expression.

Answer (score 1):

The [`psycopg2.extras.execute_values`](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/blob/d90ad8627d0a7244abeee7cd3a9418d529dc1428/lib/extras.py#L1211) function can be used in inserting many values in the table.

```py
import psycopg2.extras

psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
    cur, 
    "INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES %s", 
    ((n,) for n in nam)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [official docs for how to pass parameters to a query](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). They provide 2 methods.

**Method 1: using a sequence**

You can pass your parameters using a tuple or list, but a list may be less confusing because you don't have to remember the special case of a single element tuple.

```
nam = ['sau','sing','loe','sta'] 
for d in nam:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES ([%s])", d)
    print(len(nam))
```

**Method 2: using a dictionary**

This one seems a little clumsy, but if you have multiple parameters in your INSERT statement, it might improve readability

```
nam = ['sau','sing','loe','sta'] 
for d in nam:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages_post (pname) VALUES (%(pname)s)",
                {'pname': d} )
    print(len(nam))
```

@OluwafemiSule's answer using [`execute_values`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) is worth looking at, too. I think it comes down to personal preference to which solution is the most readable. Unless you are worried about raw speed. In that case, the docs say that `execute_values` does have some optimizations that can make it run faster than simple loops like I've shown in Method 1 and Method 2.